# ORACLE-How to manage rdf schema and instance data in multiple tables?

Tags: oracle11g, rdf, jena

I need to store the rdf schema in one table and rdf instance data in another table in ORACLE.

1. How I can do this?
2. How to configure the joseki-config.ttl to work for multiple models? Some example will help me to understand the solution.
3. Is there any possibility to create a single model for multiple tables?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use SDB with Joseki and Oracle.  Then you can have a persistent datasets (a collection of models).  There is an example of an SDB configuration in the Joseki download in joseki-config-sdb.ttl.

SDB controls the database table layout. A model is stored in the default graph name or in the named graphs table.  There is no control for other layouts without changing the code of SDB.

Note that TDB, a custom database layer for Jena, scales better and is faster than using a relational database over JDBC.  Fuseki is the new version of Joseki.

The Jena user mailing list is jena-users@incubator.apache.org.